# Is plaster repair a DIY job?

Tags: walls, plaster, lath-and-plaster

Existing plaster/lath walls in decent shape, 1920s farmhouse.
Lead/Asbestos?  Unknown but possible.

I actually like Plaster's sound-proofing and would like to keep.
Plaster has no decorative elements.

How challenging is it to learn to skim-coat these walls so they are less wavy?  Is it generally DIY-able or has someone done it before? Looking to actually use plaster.

Appreciate any guidance or help :)

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and see https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Your first question is subjective, and therefore off-topic. Your second isn't specific enough. Your third is fine, but should probably have more detail. They all should be posted separately. We're not a discussion forum and it's difficult to answer combined questions effectively.

Comment: This will most likely get closed as "Needs more focus" as it stands. Just [edit] the post down to one question (per isherwood's instructions) and it'll be good. If it gets closed before you can edit it, just edit anyway, I'm sure it will be reopened. Feel free to ask another question for your 3rd question - nobody will look down on you for asking multiple questions.

Comment: Start with a wall in a bedroom, or a hallway that isn't too obvious. Take your time and practice.  If you make a mess, either peel it off and start over, or chalk that wall up to experience and try to learn more on the next wall.

Comment: Ripping lath & plaster out isn't particularly hard.  Get a rubber mallet, tenderize the wall, and scrape it all off with a floor scraper then pry the lath off.  New drywall boards. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically use [confill](https://www.usg.com/content/usgcom/en_CA_east/products/walls/drywall/joint-compound/concrete-finishing-compounds/synko-concrete-fill.html) ( concrete fill which is a setting compound with fiberglass fibers in it ) to repair plaster as my large gap and then put a sandable top coat like a 30 minute setting compound.

How hard is it to skim coat a wall?  You could learn.  YouTube is amazing.  Start with a small wall.  You'll have to worry about putting extensions on electrical outlets, dealing with trim elements ( do you accept them more recessed with your skim coat build out above ).  Tile Coach has some good videos on tile floating to get walls perfect before tile install.

You should be able to go overtop of paint with a setting compound some people add a wood/glue mixture instead of water when mixing to get better adhesion.

It depends a lot on how wavy the walls are, how close to perfect you want them and how much time you have to spend learning and fixing.